# Towering Cistercian representation

Tags: code-golf, number, ascii-art

[SE Sandbox Link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20479/80214), [Codidact Sandbox Link](https://codegolf.codidact.com/articles/279223)

Inspired by [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9p55Qgt7Ciw&ab_channel=Numberphile)

Given a positive integer, draw its Cistercian representation as ascii art.

[image]

### The Challenge

Cistercian numerals are a decimal-based number representation system which use simple line based drawings to represent 4-digit numerals. Their structure is as follows:

```
     Tens|Units
         |
Thousands|Hundreds
```

The digits are represented as follows (in the units place):

```
1   ⌷ 2   ⌷ 3   ⌷ 4   ⌷ 5   ⌷ 6    ⌷ 7    ⌷ 8    ⌷ 9    ⌷ 0 
___ ⌷     ⌷     ⌷     ⌷ ___ ⌷    . ⌷ ___. ⌷    . ⌷ ___. ⌷
    ⌷     ⌷ \   ⌷   / ⌷   / ⌷    | ⌷    | ⌷    | ⌷    | ⌷
    ⌷     ⌷  \  ⌷  /  ⌷  /  ⌷    | ⌷    | ⌷    | ⌷    | ⌷
    ⌷ ___ ⌷   \ ⌷ /   ⌷ /   ⌷    ' ⌷    ' ⌷ ___' ⌷ ___' ⌷
```

(all of these are 4 rows in height.)

As you can see, there are some repeating patterns within the symbols:

```
5 → 4 + 1
7 → 6 + 1
8 → 6 + 2
9 → 6 + 1 + 2
```

In order to represent a general Cistercian number, you will have to place the digits in the correct place for their value.

They should be mirrored horizontally if they are on the left.

They should be mirrored vertically if they are on the bottom i.e. the lines should be reversed, `\` and `/` should be swapped, and `.` and `'` should be swapped. [Here's how they should look.](https://dzaima.github.io/paste#0y80sKsovSk1RKEstKslMTszJqbTi4jJUUFB41LNdwQhKG0NpEyhtCqXNFKAMcxjDAsawhDEMFLhgzPj4eDCtoKAPpmOg4jAaCPRQGUAdqAy4WXBaH0rHoNEKCjUEGBhm6cP5MWg0YbMQflPASiPJq8ME1LGLcHFxAQA)

The fun part is when you stack a Cistercian representation on top of another one to accommodate more digits e.g.:

```
  T|U  
   |   
 Th|H  
   |   
Hth|Tth
   |   
 TM|M
```

like a tower of sorts.

You will need to stack as many 4 part towers as the number requires, and you will need to prepend 0's to the input if it's length is not a multiple of 4.

Hence, given an input number, say, 12345, you should get the following:

`00012345 → 5432,1000`

which turns into:

```
4|5
 |
2|3
 |
0|1
 |
0|0
```

which becomes:

```
    |___
 \  |  /
  \ | /
   \|/
    |
    |
    |
    |
 ___|  /
    | /
    |/
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |___
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
```

Note that this is created by making two towers for the 4 digit numbers `2345` and `0001`, stacking them, and adding a link of 4 `|` characters between them.

## Scoring

This is code-golf. Shortest answer in each language wins.

Comment: Does this look like a box to you or something else? ```⌷``` (It renders as a box to me)

Comment: @SunnyMoon It's a box, used as a divider between the symbols.

Comment: @Noodle9 yes, that is a character.

Comment: Can we print `_`, `/`, \ just once, instead of multiple times? (ref to the numeric art)

Comment: @Noodle9 all of them are written in ascii chars.

Comment: `ᛁ ᚿ ᛚ ᚴ ꚰ |ᛌ ꛖ` it's weird that Unicode doesn't have this script... just a bit of Runic

Comment: Sorry, my bad - on my phone they looked weird.

Comment: I don't know about you but the `.`s and `'`s look weird; why not just have an extra `|` instead?

Comment: Adding annotations to the full example might help. [Here](https://tio.run/##nU9BDoIwELzzijlSEi2Knv0ICSG2CVVTCAVO/L1uW0SIcHEPzXR3dnbmUQ6lubeq6Q66FtLyxMJVURRAHiEHRoBThxA6qQ1KLdBr1RnEF5pcWeSGoyeBR446frFbpzq6J8NLaWlgnqpppFiO15iuh6v51Pd63kFV94YcBBtVr0Ur6ROfb8TJWKB79ur8hD@p5v5mqpSkTmzJ2pD6I9WMfx3spHJO0n0nNuH2DQ) is my current understanding.

Comment: Also, is an extra `¦` at the top acceptable? (Like the Perl answer does.)

Comment: Instead of adding an extra `|` at the top, do you mind if I change the single tower height to 12 lines? I feel that would make more sense.

Comment: My point is that removing the `|` on the first line is a special case that requires extra code, and the challenge is already hard enough IMO. :-) I'm not sure what you exactly mean by changing the tower height to 12 lines. Skipping 4 lines instead of 3? Personally, I don't mind. But that doesn't address the `|` issue.

Comment: @Arnauld I changed the description. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: No, each *part* is now 4 `|` characters. See the newly updated example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117153/discussion-between-razetime-and-arnauld).

Answer (score 9):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 265 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n?`01238888765${n<1e4?4:48888}`.replace(e=/\d/g,y=>`4567|3210
`.replace(e,x=>"_ \\/.'|"[q=y/2&2|x>3,y&8?1:(k='40321123'[j=~~('0x'+(1e6+'1023405671567899AB99A899CB99C')[y%4+~-(n/10**q%10)*4])]^x%4?2045>>j&1:'0122233346545'[j])^0xCC6600>>k*4+q&1]))+f(n/1e4|0):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDRboJAEHz3KxpTuDtQ2btbEEjvSMtnKFajhykaEG0aSKm/Ts@3dpPNJLPZmdmtdl@72/76cfmc183BjGOpaqXrbAtcyNjWMgqfv@sXbjDDFB/Mz3ZxNZfzbm@oUcH6EBxnvdJbDKPlIAWHyZ/5rFN6@v60XgcLMkxXreoD4Yqh03LWu3HGU3pSBMGuWTuyqtT9Tgl0xKfcRD7hICSCFea24yR5fbNtMbeYE7bqHfTvc1oHHDyvdTgwDwtWbDoHMwEYal25PCX2FiGklBiFGFqXgm2gy/MoAtD65KHfurxgzC8fSgYHYCkh476pb83ZLM7NkZbU5sOQscl/Nnn8B218xsZf)

#### Encoding

Each digit pattern is a 4x4 matrix consisting of 7 distinct characters. Each character is encoded as a single decimal digit from `0` to `6`:

```
0: "_"
1: " "
2: "\"
3: "/"
4: "."
5: "'"
6: "|"
```

All matrices are built with 13 distinct rows, encoded as a single hexadecimal digit from `0` to `C`:

```
0: 1111 for "    "
1: 0001 for "___ "
2: 2111 for "\   "
3: 1211 for " \  "
4: 1121 for "  \ "
5: 1131 for "  / "
6: 1311 for " /  "
7: 3111 for "/   "
8: 1114 for "   ."
9: 1116 for "   |"
A: 1115 for "   '"
B: 0004 for "___."
C: 0005 for "___'"
```

So, each matrix is fully described by a sequence of 4 hexadecimal digits. For instance, the matrix for `7` is encoded as `B99A`:

```
B99A -> 0004 -> "___."
        1116    "   |"
        1116    "   |"
        1115    "   '"
```

The leading sequence is `0000` and is omitted. The other sequences are stored as:

```javascript
1e6 + '1023405671567899AB99A899CB99C'
```

which expands to:

```
0      1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
(0000) 1000 0001 0234 0567 1567 899A B99A 899C B99C
```

Each matrix row is made of a 'background' character appearing 3 times and a 'foreground' character appearing only once (or not at all). So the rows can be encoded as:

- the position of the 'foreground' character (0 for rightmost to 3 for leftmost, or 4 if none)
- the 'background' character (which is always either `0` for `"_"` or `1` for `" "`)
- the 'foreground' character

This is summarized in the following table:

```
 ID | string | digits | FG position | BG char. | FG char.
----+--------+--------+-------------+----------+----------
  0 | "    " |  1111  |      4      |    1     |    0
  1 | "___ " |  0001  |      0      |    0     |    1
  2 | "\   " |  2111  |      3      |    1     |    2
  3 | " \  " |  1211  |      2      |    1     |    2
  4 | "  \ " |  1121  |      1      |    1     |    2
  5 | "  / " |  1131  |      1      |    1     |    3
  6 | " /  " |  1311  |      2      |    1     |    3
  7 | "/   " |  3111  |      3      |    1     |    3
  8 | "   ." |  1114  |      0      |    1     |    4
  9 | "   |" |  1116  |      0      |    1     |    6
  A | "   '" |  1115  |      0      |    1     |    5
  B | "___." |  0004  |      0      |    0     |    4
  C | "___'" |  0005  |      0      |    0     |    5
----+--------+--------+-------------+----------+----------
                             |           |          |
                             |           |          +--> stored as "0122233346545"
                             |           +-------------> stored as the bit mask 2045
                             +-------------------------> stored as "40321123"
```

Comment: the `2` in `12345` needs to be a bit higher, and there needs to be 4 `|` between the `0001` and `1234`.

Comment: @Razetime This is is based on what is described in [your link](https://dzaima.github.io/paste/#0y80sKsovSk1RKEstKslMTszJqbTi4jJUUFB41LNdwQhKG0NpEyhtCqXNFKAMcxjDAsawhDEMFLhgzPj4eDCtoKAPpmOg4jAaCPRQGUAdqAy4WXBaH0rHoNEKCjUEGBhm6cP5MWg0YbMQflPASiPJq8ME1LGLcHFxAQA).

Comment: ah, ok. that seems fine, then. Just needs the 4 `|` in between.

Comment: @Razetime I didn't notice you added 4 `|` between the upper and lower parts of each group. :-/ Should be fixed now. (PS: the height of your example output is 27 instead of 28.)

Comment: ah.. beautiful.

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 573 bytes

With some newlines and indentation added:

```perl
sub f{
  local$_=pop;
  s//0/ while y///c%4;
  $l="    |\n"x3;
  /.{5}/?join$l,reverse map f($_),/.{4}/g:do{
    @c{0..9}=map{join'',map{sprintf"%-4s\n",$_}(split'n')[0..3]}split$/,q(1
___
nnn___
n\n \n2\
n2/n /n/
___n2/n /n/
2.n2|n2|n2'
___.n3|n3|n3'
3.n3|n3|n___'
___.n3|n3|n___')=~s/\d/$"x$&/ger;
    $c{$_.'00'}=join('',map"$_\n",reverse$c{$_}=~/.+/g)=~y|.'|'.|r=~y|/\\|\\/|r for 0..9;
    $c{$_.0}=$c{$_}=~s,.+,reverse"|$&",ger=~y|/\\|\\/|r for map{$_,$_.'00'}0..9;
    $_=[/.+/g]for values%c;
    /(.)(.)(.)(.)/;
    join'',
      (map$c{$3.0}[$_].$c{$4}[$_].$/,0..3),
      $l,
      map$c{$1.'000'}[$_].$c{$2.'00'}[$_].$/,0..3
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFhb5swEP3Or7Aspwb15iNAtnUIbf8jRBajTsZEDcNpmwrcv57ZhESdhk7ine/de@dzr4Z2c9Ydea0G3eiDIVydejU0T0ofq5bnQT80@kgooackBkqYpMAQ9iGTEdl3A4lhDQmkkMEGPsMX@AoPsE7SbJOfzfNPsh/brq5aJou@63ODGCN5/dW0irwhYr3KctYWlLhvKjU9pTmKcWPx@@@u0ayFQb2owSjyVPVk9gRXzywevj124496jIV4sIWrjr6Bc/DQzDPv6epTZpwoMGlD07fNkWsebV1LurNz7i7yJ1wHUspAaz3/Sk1KnZSBTlAT1OiLN5wInUxzcH8udDrNwYP0it3xPzWfR8W7wfIRGT2xOzyoIWf1yKTgccxt4QcPL5NTJv28y6Vnki3eUdzjwWm8TYJPXEyDh1iWU1niNFwewa1hEY1tcW00IO6vYnRidxSc9//NfmVMwnWgi5YstrPvzjNeqvZZmVWdYyiiW2C@7Dx0Ct4zdeZbJnfCJ9kCEfzCI3CPudDW3scZ3ajJxfgj39rz@S8)

Comment: the specification has changed a bit, so each segment needs to be 4 lines long now,

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 125 bytes

```
≔⪪⮌Ｓ⁴θＦＬθ«↓∧ι⁴Ｆ⁴«→Ｐ§⪪”~∨VKＴ✂≦M›ζΦNＦ›ιO:υ⊘[⁸À1“ir⊞Py✳⪫℅⁰ψ"´dＤ?5¬→⁼σm‹1“"ξωＴ\⁵⁻Hïg”⸿Σ§◨§θι⁴κ←‖Ｔ¿﹪κ²«↓¹¹‖Ｔ↓»»↓¹²»ＵＭＫＡ⎇№βι§.'›ιdι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJda8IwFIav218RerMEuonOfbmr4mAIFkS9LEi0aQ2mSU1Tt7H52@tJqjJRmpyU9zynnPOmqzXVK0VF00RVxXOJZ6XgBk/ZjumK4ZEsazMzmsscExKiPuwtefczpREeM5mbNd4Sgn59bwKQwYMP9SVDFMkUc4sD6zm47yAvVjuGB1Oer41NeXEtDC9daWRGMmXfxw6CRC8Wi0Qn0j6n1ySRyAUbtT07EGB3WvxCQAgtrYL@/sXSgTf1ax7Im7zVgxBBjwEYMquLc/MTmrrhzsI2RPxo3IYQ0g7tTBizrPVgyjLBVmauqazAqwI7lWcIxyqthcKbEPVak71Lm7tdh15/weVdbu/bdVnVg8zej2k5VEVB4aomjG0iITA0OWdaUv2Dh6qGimXb/WmY4OEOxv7UjBqm7QUHaWB/Cw5zNU2399h/en55fWvud@IA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⪪⮌Ｓ⁴θ
```

Split the reversed input into substrings of length 4.

```
ＦＬθ«
```

Loop over each substring.

```
↓∧ι⁴
```

Except for the first substring, separate each quad of digits with a vertical line of length 4.

```
Ｆ⁴«
```

Loop over each digit in the quad.

```
→Ｐ§⪪”~∨VKＴ✂≦M›ζΦNＦ›ιO:υ⊘[⁸À1“ir⊞Py✳⪫℅⁰ψ"´dＤ?5¬→⁼σm‹1“"ξωＴ\⁵⁻Hïg”⸿Σ§◨§θι⁴κ←
```

Extract the relevant digit from a compressed string of all digits and print it without moving the cursor. (I tried printing the digits by parts but this was at least 16 bytes longer.) Note that at this point I print `b` instead of `.` and `p` instead of `'` as Charcoal knows how to reflect `b`, `d`, `p` and `q`.

```
‖Ｔ
```

Reflect the canvas horizontally, transforming the characters appropriately. There are four reflections in total, so that the units end up with their original orientation, but the tens end up horizontally reflected.

```
¿﹪κ²«
```

On alternate passes, ...

```
↓¹¹
```

... move down 11 lines (actually drawing is golfier, but moving would work), ...

```
‖Ｔ↓
```

... and reflect the canvas vertically. This happens twice, so the units and tens end up with their original reflection, but the hundreds and thousands are vertically reflected (and the thousands also get an overall horizontal reflection).

```
»»↓¹²
```

Print the vertical line down the middle of the four digits.

```
»ＵＭＫＡ⎇№βι§.'›ιdι
```

Translate the `b` (and its horizontal reflection `d`) to `.` and the `p` (and its horizontal reflection `q`) to `'`. `b` and `p` (and `d` and `q`) are also vertical reflections of each other, but we want that, otherwise the `.`s and `'`s would be exchanged by the vertical reflection.